# Recursively redirect all PDF's with .htaccess rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to come up with a rule that will redirect all PDFs to a different directory recursively, retaining the path aside from the change I'm making.

Initial directory is */wp-content/uploads*
Target directory is */build/wp-content/uploads*

So /wp-content/uploads/2013/03/LW_Stevens.pdf

Would redirect to /build/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/LW_Stevens.pdf

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/*/(.+\.pdf)$ build/wp-content/uploads/*/$1 [L]
```

Obviously the /*/ part is wrong, how would I do this correctly?

Comment: Depends on what you need to match. `(.*)` will match anything and return the value to $1 (changing your filename reference to $2). You can refine it to limit your match to valid paths, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion to match with or without a path after initial directory.
If there is no path after the initial directory, it will be ignored.

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content\/uploads\/(?:(.+)\/)?(.+\.pdf)$ build/wp-content/uploads/$1/$2 [L]
```

You can see the returned matches here:
http://rubular.com/r/16io6ZVSJc

Answer (score 1):

Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads/.*?/[^.]+\.pdf)$ /build/$1 [L,NC]
```

And make sure this rule is placed above other standard Wordpress rules in your .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Using a mix from both answers for wordpress.

Plugin: Redirection by John Godley

Redirection type: regex
origin url: ^(/pdfs/(?:(.+)/)?(.+.pdf))
destination url: URL$1